# Error:error: ../../../../openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(err.o): incompatible target

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl

I want to include openssl in my project. I copied libraries from [this example](https://github.com/leenjewel/openssl_for_ios_and_android/releases/tag/android_openssl-1.1.0f_curl-7.54.1) but I am getting error like above I mentioned . I linked in cmake like below

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                   native-lib
                    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a
                    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libssl.a
                   # Links the target library to the log library
                   # included in the NDK.
                   ${log-lib} )
```

I am not getting where i am doing wrong? or is it a wrong way to include openssl in project.?

build.graddle is here

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.manvish.rsa"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions"
            }
        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: What have you set your `abiFilter` to? Post your `build.gradle`.

Comment: @Michael it looks like this  ndk {
            abiFilters "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"
        }

Comment: Well, you can't use openssl-armeabi-v7a for anything other than armeabi-v7a. You'll either have to drop support for those other ABIs, or build openssl for them as well.

Comment: @Michael sir tell me what should i need to do now. even after removing abiFilters also i am getting same problem.

Comment: I am obliged to remind you that using prebuilt libraries in general may involve security risk; doing so for the libraries that you rely upon for security should not be taken lightly.

Comment: were you able to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your **cmake** script must choose the ABI dynamically. Android Studio will provide it as `-DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a`, *etc.*

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
  native-lib
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/openssl-${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libcrypto.a
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/openssl-${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libssl.a
   # Links the target library to the log library
   # included in the NDK.
   ${log-lib} )
```

And don't remove **abiFilters**! Maybe, you can remove `armeabi`: there are very few devices that need it today. According to [Unity stsatistics](https://hwstats.unity3d.com/mobile/cpu-android.html), on March 2017, they saw 98.1% **armeabi-v7a** devices and 1.7% **x86** devices. All the rest was 0.2%.

Comment: I change CMake as you suggested like this ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libcrypto.a
                        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libssl.a

Comment: Now i am getting error like this needed by '../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libnative-lib.so', missing and no known rule to make it

Comment: I am afraid you should post the full **CMakeLists.txt** script and the full error log, not just few lines that are out of context.